# dynamic iframe in ui.dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe

I'm trying to dynamically create an iframe in my dialog and I have it working but not really because I only works sometimes here is the code

```
 function test(obj){
    if($('#wa').length === 0){ // check if we have already created iframe and dialog
        $('body').append('<div id="wa"></div>'); //add a div for the the iframe to go into
        $("#wa").dialog({  //apply a ui dialog
            autoOpen: false,
            bgiframe: false,
            modal: true,
            autoResize: true,
            buttons: {
                Submit: function() {
                    $('#iframe').contents().find('#f').submit();
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
           }    
        });
    }

    $('#iframe').remove();
    var $frame = $('<iframe id="iframe" width="100%" height="325"></iframe>');
    $('#wa').append($frame); // add iframe to created div
     var tm2 = setTimeout( function() {//apply content to iframe
        var doc = $frame[0].contentWindow.document;
        var $body = $('body',doc);
        $body.html('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">'+
        '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">'+
        '<head>'+
        '<title>test iframe</title>'+
        '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />'+
        '<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />'+
        '<form name="f" id="f" action="https://example.com" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="post">'+
            '<fieldset>'+
                '<label>test1:</label>'+
                '<input type="text" name="test1" value="" size="15" class="required"/>'+
                '<label>test2:</label>'+
                '<input type="text" name="test2" value="" size="15" autocomplete="off" class="required" />'+
                '<input type="submit" value="Login" />'+
            '</fieldset>'+
        '</form></body></html>');
    }, 1 );

    $("#wa").dialog('open');//open the dialog
 }

 $('body').append('<input type="button" id="test" value="test" />');
 $('#test').click(function(){
    test();
 });
```

Comment: And what isn't working, when it sometimes doesn't work?

Comment: ahh yes the form doesn't show up in the iframe

Comment: I suspect that the problem is with trying to use the iframe document directly in that $('body', doc) jquery call.  I'd open the iframe window and use `document.write` to put the form in there.

Comment: I think the problem is I'm trying to set the content before the iframe is loaded and I"m have trouble on testing that as well

Answer (score 1):

There is a Frame Dialog Plug-in available...
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-framedialog

Comment: no - I don't need another plugin infact it would defeat the purpose notice that the iframe source is empty I'm trying to populate the iframe aafter it has been appended to the parent body  thank you though